# PlanningEntities split across multiple collections

Tags: java, optaplanner, domain-model

I am writing a staff scheduler for my office. There are at least two shifts per day (7 days a week) and I want the optimizer to make sure no one staff member works drastically more weekend shifts than another.

I have a simple working program that assigns one **Staff** to each **Shift**.
The program structure is as follows:

- **SchedulingSolution** is the *@PlanningSolution*
- **SchedulingSolution** contains a List<**Shift**> which is the *@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty*
- **Shift** is the @PlanningEntity
- **Shift** contains a **Staff** which is the *@PlanningVariable*
- **SchedulingSolution** contains a *@ValueRangeProvider* which returns our staff roster as a List<**Staff**>.

This working solution schedules all staff equally but does not consider weekends and weekdays. To delineate weekdays from weekends, I have replaced the List<**Shift**> in **SchedulingSolution** with a List<**Day**>. Every **Day** contains its own List<**Shift**> representing the shifts that occur on that day. Now when I want to compute the number of weekends a staff member has worked, I can find all **Day** objects that represent weekends and count only the **Shifts** contained in those days.

Unfortunately, this places the List<**Shift**> which is the *@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty* in a class that is not a *@PlanningSolution*. The *@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty* annotation is now ignored and the program fails.

Have I missed an obvious way to restructure my program, or is my only option to keep my original program structure and modify my **shift** objects to record which day they occur on?

Thanks in advance. I'll try to pass the help forward if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would restructure your Planning Solution.

Why don't you do:

- Keep the `List<Shift>` in the `Planning Solution`
- Discard the `List<Day>` in every shift
- Add a field `day` in `Shift`, possibly even an indicator whether that day is a weekend using an enum.

You can then easily calculate the number of weekend days worked by each staff with Drools as so:

(Absolutely untested!!!)

```
rule "balancedStaffWeekend"
    when
        $staff: Staff()
        accumulate(
            Shift(
                staff == $staff
                day == Day.WEEKEND);
                $count: count()
            );
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -Math.pow(count, 2));
end
```

Penalising the solution by counts raised to the power of two balances the number of weekends.

Comment: Thanks! Looking back at the examples, it appears that it is necessary to have the PlanningSolution keep track of the PlanningEntityCollectionProperty directly with no intermediate classes. I have done just as you suggested and each Shift now references a Workday which has a Date and a DayType from an Enum. I'm still learning Drools but I mocked up an EasyScoreCalculator that works just fine. Thank you for helping me learn this new and valuable skill!